# Azure Boards moving issues to "Done" status automatically

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We have had two stories moved from "In Progress" to "Done" status by Azure Boards automatically. From what I can tell we don't have any rules set for it and can't seem to find out why the system is automatically moving stories. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated, I am afraid we are going to miss items that actually need to be worked.

[image]

Comment: Was it linked to a PR that was completed?

Comment: According to the screenshot, seems the `Azure Boards` is just the display name of an user. Except linked to a PR, another possibility is that, you selected the `Resolve` option for the linked work item(s) when you perform the check-in in the Pending Changes window with VS client. See https://xebia.com/blog/changing-the-default-checkin-action-in-tfs/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

If the *story* on the Azure DevOps board is linked to some code branch or pull request in the code repository, changes to the repository can update the status of the *story*. For example, if you link the *story* to some Pull Request* (as stated by @Daniel Mann), and then you complete that *Pull Request*, the *story* will automatically be moved to "Done" state.

You can check the **Development** and **Related Work** sections of the *story* (usually on the right) to see if it has some link to the code.